# Resampled series with timedeltas does not start at zero

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta, pandas-resample

I would like to resample a pandas series with `timedelta` starting with the zero interval (`timedelta(seconds=0)`) instead of the first occurrence.

For example, for

```
from datetime import timedelta
from random import sample
s = pd.Series(1, index=[timedelta(minutes=m) for m in sample(range(1, 100), 10)])
s.resample('1h').count()
```

I get

```
0 days 00:12:00    9
0 days 01:12:00    1
```

But I need

```
0 days 00:00:00    9
0 days 01:00:00    0    
0 days 02:00:00    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `to_offset`.

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
s_res = s.resample('1h').count()
```

We compute the current minute index start

```
minute_start = (s.index.seconds%3600//60).min()
```

Then modify the index

```
s_res.index = s_res.index - to_offset(f'{minute_start}min')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an item `0 days 00:00:00` in your `timedelta` series, which serves as the bottom boundary. If you look at the examples in the pandas documentation for `resample()` method you will realize that the `range` in all their examples starts from `0` (at least for the type of groupby results you are looking for).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from random import sample

my_sample = sample(range(1, 100), 10)
my_sample.append(0)

s = pd.Series(1, index=[timedelta(minutes=m) for m in my_sample])
print(s.min)
s.resample('1h').count()
```